# Registering AppImage within a system

Tags: .desktop, appimage

I am trying to add AppImage to a Start Menu under the category Utilities but it gets put under Lost & Found. When I change the category from Utilities to RandomCatName it still gets put under Lost & Found. How to enable custom categories or Utilities to be able to store my AppImage?

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Electrum LTC
Comment=Electrum Litecoin Wallet
Exec=/opt/electrum-ltc-3.3.8.1-x86_64.appimage
Icon=/var/lib/flatpak/appstream/flathub/x86_64/2df811d1f8f90f95682e6b299f9f13b3d5373795fa1b2ade190d2376733d6968/icons/128x128/electrum-ltc.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utilities
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `Utility` instead as category. `Utilities` is not a [registered application category](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/apa.html).

Comment: Thanks! That really did help! How to register an application category? I.e. I would like to put this appimage under a custom category 'cryptography'

Comment: You can put categories different to the standard ones on the Categorie line, but how these are then handled depends on your desktop environment, or al least your menuing system.

Comment: If I put custom category in Category line, the AppImage gets put under Lost & Found category

Comment: What desktop environment do you use? Standard Ubuntu (Gnome Shell)?

Comment: K Desktop Environment Plasma